# How do I get a function that makes a random number to be called when submitted and then post to the cell in a database

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I am new to web development, with around three months of experience. I am making a website for a friend, and I made a form where the data can be entered into a database. I wanted to make an ID for each form to log it and pull it back up from the database(this part is not made). To give context, the form is for painting jobs. So you would fill out the form. Hit submit, and it will log it with an ID that the JS function would make. Then you could put the id in the search bar (when I make it), and it will find the data logged with that submission. This, of course, would be set up with a server database.

Now my problem is the form is sent, and the function is called, but it seems to save before the new data has been entered, resulting in nothing being logged. I have tested this with other fields, and it inputs fine, so I know the paths to the form, and things are working. I am unsure if there is a certain place it needs to go or anything like that. Could someone come to help me with this?

````
    <form id="workOrder" method="POST" action="This would be path to DB">
        <lable for="Name">Name</lable>
            <input id="name" name="name" required>
        
        <lable for="orderPackage">Order Package</lable>
            <input id="orderpackage" name="orderPackage">
        
            <input id="orderNum" name="workNumber" hidden>
        
            <input type="Submit" value="submit"/>

            <script>
                function workNumber(){
                    const WONum = Math.floor((Math.random()*10000)+1);
                    document.getElementById("orderNum").innerHTML = workNumber();
                }
                alert('Thanks, your order has been sent'); 
            </script>
    </form>
</section>```
````

Comment: The problem that you are having is you are adding the alert on the load of the page, so it will always show as being sent. Also you aren't actually calling the **workNumber** function anywhere.  The function exists but isn't being called. You don't even need it in a function but if you want to keep it in the function at the bottom of your script tag add **workNumber();*

Comment: Thank you for coming back to me. I now see the issues, so thanks. However, calling it at the bottom didn't fix it for some reason. So I placed it inside an onclick="workNumber" and did it that way. That still did not work. I changed the function name from workNumber to WorkNumber, and it worked immediately. I am rather confused as to why soon, as it's not capital at the start; it just doesn't work.  I also changed some things as well to make it this. It works so I guess that's a bonus. If you have info on how I can improve the process please let me know.  I will list the changes below

Comment: ```function WorkNumber() {
                    var orderNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
                    document.getElementById("orderNum").value = orderNum;
                }``

Comment: I just noticed another problem. I see that you fixed it in the code that you provided, but I will still mention it. In your original function are you calling the function **workNumber** inside of itself by using **innerHTML = workNumber()**. Which is called a recursive function. And that means it is a never ending loop. Unless you know why and how they should work, I recommend avoiding doing that.

Comment: I don't think the case matters, It could have been something else causing the problem and it was just a coincidence that you changed the case.

Comment: I see, well thanks for your help. I have made notes of this. See you in the next coding issue ^^.